# Reverse SE: Technology or Human based?

Tags: social-engineering

In **Reverse Social Engineering** the hacker deliberately sabotages a network, causing a problem to arise. That hacker then advertises that he is the appropriate contact to fix the problem, and when he or she comes to fix the network problem, the hacker requests certain bits of information from the employees or staff and acquires the information he or she was looking
for.

I would categorize RSE under *technology*, because I can't seem to come up with an example that is not based on technology.

Can you come up with a RSE scenario that does not involve technology?

- What could be sabotaged?
- How will you justify your request for security information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Social Engineering and Reverse social engineering are mainly used in computer security however they can be applied outside this field as well.

Both social and reverse social engineering exploit the non-technical **human weakness** in security therefor the actual exploitation occurs outside the computer.

One **example** of social engineering is creating distrust, which in fact can be used in reverse social engineering as well. After creating distrust between two target parties (possibly by falsifying or altering information) he can then introduce himself as a "mediator" for fixing the conflict. The mediator is then able to acquire security information from both parties.

**Another example** is causing a maintenance problem in a building (power black-out) and then arriving dressed-up as the maintenance repair-man to fix the problem and in doing so, gain access to the building and maybe the sensitive systems inside.

The main reasons that make social engineering attacks successful are:

- **Poor Security Awareness**: An extremely large
  percentage of users do not understand the importance of a password for authentication and
  access to a computer system. They do not realize that their account can be accessed from
  anywhere in the world, given the proper access point.
  Users also do not understand the lengths that people will go to obtain the information
  that the users have access to on a daily basis. They also do not realize that throwing
  something in the garbage does not mean that the information is destroyed. What is garbage
  to a user might be extremely valuable to a hacker.
- **Human Weaknesses**: People give out information for many reasons. In most cases, they just want to be
  helpful, because that is their job and/or nature. People can also be intimidated to release
  information, either by being made to believe that a superior wants the information or by just
  trying to make an annoying person go away.
- **Untested Plans and Procedures**: Organizational procedures that require an authenticating mechanism must carry with
  them additional procedures that protect the mechanism. This is where a large number of
  security plans fail. Many organizations test a specific part of a security plan or procedure,
  but these plans and procedures must be tested as a whole.

Based on the above, most social and reverse social engineering scenarios are based on technology because the general public is not aware of the security significance of certain information. But social engineering was used long before computers were born (the words **"con"** and **"scam"** refer to a more general non-technological form of social engineering). However with the evolution of technology there has been new and intuitive ways to accomplish this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

*The plumber... he is not a plumber.*

This is a classic plot point in movies. For instance, the attacker (who may be the "good guy" in a movie setup) creates a more or less fake fire, and when the smoke appears, he shows up dressed as a fireman. The security guards, all panicked about the fire, let him go through.

If you want something more computer-related, then just consider the very common "hello this is Microsoft" phone-based attack. Context: you are in your home, comfortably bathing in idleness, and then the phone rings. Some guy at the other end (usually with a heavy accent) claims that he is "from Microsoft" and that there is a security issue with your computer. If you agree to swallow this, then he will guide you through some actions on your computer which culminate in your installing on your own machine what is, actually, a piece of malware which grants remote control of your computer by the bad guy. At which point various mischief is enacted, including grabbing your passwords and so on.

(I got more than 20 times that fake phone call. It quickly grows old.)

This illustrates how such attacks operate: the first step is to push the victim out of his comfort zone, because panicking people are prone to disregard security procedures. Fire is very good for that: *everybody* strongly believes that an ongoing fire is a kind of issue that trumps any kind of security. As the "phone call" example shows, vague "security issues" can also serve to trigger worry-induced vulnerability, and, crucially, *the initial hazard needs not be real*. In the fire example, you don't need actual flames, only smoke.

I don't see the point in inventing a three-letter acronym for something which is a very classic scam. It is more biology than technology: the vulnerability is not in the computer, but in the human operator.